# Merge 2 hashes by matching different keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, merge

First query:

```
>> Player.all
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [
#<Player id: 1, first_name: "Daniel", last_name: "Margush", aleague_club: "AU", position: "GLK", created_at: "2018-03-16 10:21:08", updated_at: "2018-03-16 10:21:08">, 
#<Player id: 2, first_name: "Michael", last_name: "Marrone", aleague_club: "AU", position: "DEF", created_at: "2018-03-16 10:21:08", updated_at: "2018-03-16 10:21:08">, 
#<Player id: 3, first_name: "Ben", last_name: "Warland", aleague_club: "AU", position: "DEF", created_at: "2018-03-16 10:21:08", updated_at: "2018-03-16 10:21:08">, 
#<Player id: 4, first_name: "Taylor", last_name: "Regan", aleague_club: "AU", position: "DEF", created_at: "2018-03-16 10:21:08", updated_at: "2018-03-16 10:21:08">, 
#<Player id: 5, first_name: "Vince", last_name: "Lia", aleague_club: "AU", position: "DMD", created_at: "2018-03-16 10:21:08", updated_at: "2018-03-16 10:21:08">, 
#<Player id: 6, first_name: "Ryan", last_name: "Kitto", aleague_club: "AU", position: "AMD", created_at: "2018-03-16 10:21:08", updated_at: "2018-03-16 10:21:08">, 
 #<Player id: 7, first_name: "", last_name: "Isaias", aleague_club: "AU", position: "DMD", created_at: "2018-03-16 10:21:08", updated_at: "2018-03-16 10:21:08">, 
#<Player id: 8, first_name: "Baba", last_name: "Diawara", aleague_club: "AU", position: "STK", created_at: "2018-03-16 10:21:08", updated_at: "2018-03-16 10:21:08">, 
#<Player id: 9, first_name: "Karim", last_name: "Matmour", aleague_club: "AU", position: "WNG", created_at: "2018-03-16 10:21:08", updated_at: "2018-03-16 10:21:08">, 
#<Player id: 10, first_name: "Johan", last_name: "Absalonsen", aleague_club: "AU", position: "WNG", created_at: "2018-03-16 10:21:08", updated_at: "2018-03-16 10:21:08">, ...]>
```

Second query:

```
>> PlayerTransaction.where(league_id: 1).select("DISTINCT ON(player_id) player_id, updated_at, transaction_type, value, club_id").order("player_id, updated_at DESC")
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [
#<PlayerTransaction id: nil, transaction_type: nil, player_id: "1", value: 313387, club_id: 8, updated_at: "2018-03-16 10:21:08">, 
#<PlayerTransaction id: nil, transaction_type: nil, player_id: "2", value: 623542, club_id: 4, updated_at: "2018-03-16 10:21:08">, 
#<PlayerTransaction id: nil, transaction_type: nil, player_id: "4", value: 488987, club_id: 5, updated_at: "2018-03-16 10:21:08">, 
#<PlayerTransaction id: nil, transaction_type: nil, player_id: "6", value: 345036, club_id: 5, updated_at: "2018-03-16 10:21:08">, 
#<PlayerTransaction id: nil, transaction_type: nil, player_id: "8", value: 830195, club_id: 7, updated_at: "2018-03-16 10:21:08">,....
```

I want to merge the result of PlayerTransaction query into the result of the Player query so, based on comparison of keys PlayerTransaction.player_id and Player.id, that I'm left with something like:

```
#<Player id: 1, first_name: "Daniel", last_name: "Margush", aleague_club: "AU", position: "GLK", created_at: "2018-03-16 10:21:08", value: 313387, club_id: 8, updated_at: "2018-03-16 10:21:08">, 
#<Player id: 2, first_name: "Michael", last_name: "Marrone", aleague_club: "AU", position: "DEF", created_at: "2018-03-16 10:21:08", value: 623542, club_id: 4, updated_at: "2018-03-16 10:21:08">, 
#<Player id: 3, first_name: "Ben", last_name: "Warland", aleague_club: "AU", position: "DEF", created_at: "2018-03-16 10:21:08", updated_at: "2018-03-16 10:21:08">, 
#<Player id: 4, first_name: "Taylor", last_name: "Regan", aleague_club: "AU", position: "DEF", created_at: "2018-03-16 10:21:08", value: 488987, club_id: 5, updated_at: "2018-03-16 10:21:08">, 
#<Player id: 5, first_name: "Vince", last_name: "Lia", aleague_club: "AU", position: "DMD", created_at: "2018-03-16 10:21:08", updated_at: "2018-03-16 10:21:08">,...
```

As you can see Players with id's 1,2,4 have the additional values.

Comment: You don't have hashes, you have ActiveRecord queries. Wouldn't it make more sense to do a JOIN?

Comment: Thanks for your advice, it may make more sense to do a join but that was not obvious to me due to my lack of experience. I will investigate that.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like below:

```
Player.joins(:player_transactions).select("players.id, player_transactions.update_at, player_transactions.transaction_type, player_transactions.value, player_transactions.club_id").where(league_id: 1)
```